# Creating a helper function to create an associative array not sure where my logic is wrong

Tags: javascript

I am looping over a large data set that is constructed as follows:

```
{Date: "5.10.13", Activity: "1", Date: "7/17/14", Device: "mobile", Gender: "female", Time"8:07 PM"},
{Date: "5.10.13", Activity: "1", Date: "7/17/14", Device: "mobile", Gender: "female", Time: "10:07 PM"},
{Date: "5.10.13", Activity: "1", Date: "7/17/14", Device: "mobile", Gender: "female", Time: "11:07 PM"},
```

For each day, I am trying to create an associative array with that day's total stats per hour. I have this code, which is working but is verbose to keep typing over and over. the "key" is an hour of the day in military time.  I am looping over the data and creating a key for each hour(if its not there) and then adding up the activity stats if I have multiple activity records in that hour.

```
  if(key in dayHours){
     dayHours[key].Activity = dayHours[key].Activity + d.Activity

  }else{
  dayHours[key] = {Activity: d.Activity }
```

I created this helper function to take over the task, since I have to build up many keys and totals.

```
function lookUp(array, value, key, level){
  value = Number(value);
  level = String(level);

  if(key in array){
    array[key].level = array[key].level + value
  }else{
    array[key] = {level : value}
  }
};
```

I tried calling the function with this

```
lookUp(dayHours, d.Time, key, Activity)
```

unfortunately it doesn't work and says that Activity is undefined.  I don't understand why it comes back undefined.

Also, I am somewhat new to programming so if there is a better method that I should be investigating please point me in the right direction.  THANKS!!!

Comment: Please show an example of the expected output.  I can't tell from your code exactly what this is supposed to achieve.

Comment: "I tried calling the function with this

`lookUp(dayHours, d.Time, key, Activity)`"



Where do you define the `Activity` variable?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to use the word `Activity` to reflect the field name in the original structure.

As such it needs to be a string variable (not a "bare word") and also therefore needs to use `obj[key]` rather than `obj.key` syntax.

I haven't provided code because I believe there are further issues that will not be revealed until you have attempted to fix the above, and also shown the expected output of your process.  I'd also strongly recommend that your summary data *not* be stored in the original array.

Comment: Thank you - your correct about how I was trying to use Activity.  I see how  it needs to string variable.  I will keep this in mind.  And yes,  Im  sure there are other problems going on here.  Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this common "totalling" problem with

```
dayHours[key].activity = (((dayHours[key] && dayHours[key].activity)||0)
                          + d.activity);
```

it works because in Javascript `&&` returns the second value if the first is "falsy" and similarly `||` returns the second value if the first is "truthy".

This means that if `key` is not present in `dayHours` or if `activity` is not present in `dayHours[key]` then `0` will be used as addend.

This is very common in the simplified form:

```
total[key] = (total[key] || 0) + value;
```

PS: Pay attention that every object in Javascript contains (inherits) a `constructor` field (i.e. `"constructor" in {}` is true). If `key` is a string that could possibly assume the value `"constructor"` you may run into problems.

Comment: Great - thanks so much.  I will play around with that.  Much bettter implementation.